# How much padding should this Activity's root layout have, as per material design specification?

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to immitate the search interface shown in the first image in [this documentation on the specification about the Search pattern in Material Design.](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search)

But I can not find any information on how much distance is there between the SearchView and the edge of the Activity's frame, i.e. the `padding` applied to the root layout of the Activity.

**How do I know for sure how much padding should I apply to root layout of the Activity, in accordance with Material design specification?**

**What I have tried:**

In [this specification of Metrics and Keylines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing), particularly in [this image](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsMHFJN3BXcjl2NmM/layout_metrics_keyline_mobile11.png), they have shown a `paddingLeft` of `16dp`, but the padding applied in the following picture doesn't seem to have `16dp`, and neither does Google Now app, actually this padding, that is the one applied in the following picture is nothing more than like `8dp`.

[image]

Comment: Somebody gave a downvote. I'll be grateful if you can tell me the reason? Am I going too overboard with the details? Am I going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst not strictly Material Design specific, the `@dimen/activity_vertical_margin` is commonly defined as `16dp` within Android applications.

This is commonly used across many applications and the design guidelines.

It should be noted that the horizontal margin *does* differ over screen sizes according to the Material Design guidelines.

`res/values/dimens.xml` usually specifies:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

Whilst you will commonly see `res/values-w820dp/dimens.xml` for tablet devices specify:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
```